# Taking data from a fake api for a todo app created using react and redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I'm a beginner to ReactJS and Redux and currently I'm developing a todos application using ReactJS and Redux and in the need of fetching the todos from a fake api...how to get an api key and an api for the purpose?

Comment: how to use jsonplaceholder fake api to fetch data to my todo app developed using ReactJS and Redux?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jsonplaceholder for your purpose.

[Todos](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos) jsonplaceholder provides.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to implement your own api for this purpose so that you can modify it according to your needs. However you can use [Microsoft To Do's API](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-microsoft-to-do-s-api-f944256d-3b08-4945-ba69-2c17afeb60b4) for your convenience. There is complete list of actions provided by this api in the right side menu of [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/task-rest-operations).